# Encounter error "NSInternalInconsistencyException"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I have been trying to develop a side menu by using Apple UISplitView Controller. The data has been populate to MasterVC, but when I select the row and the XCode prompted this log.

> Assertion failure in -[UIStoryboardPushSegueTemplate
>   newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3505.16/UIStoryboardPushSegueTemplate.m:45
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unexpected number of view
>   controllers (1) for split view controller ''. Expected at least 2 view controllers to be present,
>   to perform a push segue for index 1.'

Do not hesitate for further clarification.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMxNz.png [Storyboard here][1]

Update: Solved with Push segue (Master split)

Comment: What are you doing in your did select row at indexpath?

Comment: It shall performs the segue, eg the row is 1,2,3. When I select the row 1, the detail1 VC should displayed.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard or are you creating the view controller programatically?

Comment: Using storyboard, sorry for did not mention at first. I also suspect my storyboard was causing the error.